# BeginOutputReadLine and encoding

Tags: c#, process, io-redirection

I'm using `Process.BeginOutputReadLine()` which sends text lines to `StringBuilder` via events. However, `BeginOutputReadLine()` does not recognize output encoding. Process that I launch returns string in `UCS-2 LE` format. So `BeginOutputReadLine()` returns string like that `"\0T\0e\0s\0t"`. Previously I have used `StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` which have feature to auto-detect encoding.
Docs says StreamReader.Read(...) will use first call to determine encoding (so StreamReader.CurrentEncoding will be set). `BeginOutputReadLine()` create internal `AsyncStreamReader` and pases encoding to its ctor from `Process.StandardOutput.CurrentEncoding` - which is not yet detected.

How to avoid this issue? I need to grab output in real time while process is running. Tried to create Task which reads line by line, raise events to pass data to StringBuilder but finally it blows :/

Comment: It is not its job to recognize the encoding, redirected console mode apps are expected to use the default system codepage.  The only shot you have is to set the ProcessStartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding property to Encoding.Unicode

Comment: Damn, I need to setup this property for each process I launch manually. Maybe no autodetection but it works. Thanks.